Can I buy replacement bags through Lego?
Several years ago I bought the Millennium Falcon through AliExpress for my son. He began putting it together but I think he was a little too young at that point and he abandoned it. Now he wants to build it but we seem to be missing two entire bag numbers. I'm fairly sure all were there originally and we've misplaced them. Do the bag numbers for the AliExpress "Lego" match those for the actual Lego? I'd like to see if I can buy replacements from Lego but I don't know if numbers 4 and 15 in my son's build are the same as they would be for true Lego. Thanks!

Have you actually asked Lego customer service? They're an email away and will give you a definite answer.

I guess I feel kind of bad asking them since I didn't buy their product, but that's probably what I should do.

Perhaps you can be more specific which clone brand and which model you've bought. AliExpress is just a platform offering several clone brands...

Lego customer service will send you missing parts free of charge as long as they still exist. I was surprised that I couldn’t pay for them. Not sure about missing bags.

If they do sell complete bags (don’t know if they do) then they make more money selling it than not selling it, so no need to have a bad conscience. If they give them to you for free and you feel bad about it, donate some money to some good cause and if possible hide the receipt somewhere inside the build.

I don't know what AliExpress sells, but for genuine LEGO sets customer service typically does not store the bags that are in sets, but if it's not too old, they probably have all the parts (possibly except minifigures from licensed - like Star Wars - sets). But they probably won't have an inventory of the bags, so you'll have to make a list of the individual parts - that work is yours, and the resulting list might be quite long.
So if you bought a genuine LEGO set, and "several years ago" isn't too long, you might be able to order the parts - parts that are in active (i.e. currently sold) sets, should be in stock, parts that are not is where time becomes an issue, it also matters how many copies they've had to send out to others, so it's impossible to say what the time limit is - and they've made several versions of the Millenium Falcon, so we can't use that to guess.
I don't know if customer service will even handle a request like that, but if they do it will probably be expensive. And with the list of parts it might be cheaper to look at Bricklink for the parts.

If I were in your shoes, I'd first check if the off-brand Falcon is really the same as the official one. Use the building instructions and - if provided - the parts list to compare the two. If they are different, then all bets are off.
If they do match (aka it's an identical, therefore unauthorized bootleg copy), then it's quite straightforward (but time-consuming) to compile the list of all missing parts, which can then be ordered from second-hand sellers or Lego's own Pick-a-Brick service.
Depending on the original price you paid, the cost of the replacement parts and your valuation of your own time, it might not be that bad a deal compared to the going price of an authentic Millennium Falcon. But keep this in mind the next time before ordering non-LEGO sets, that part of the official price goes to ensure no such thing happens to any customer.

I think OP or his young son lost two complete bags with parts.

@gnasher729 yes, that's clear. What's not, is whether the bags of the counterfeit set have the same contents as the ones from TLG, or even if the set is identical. If some parts have been added, removed or exchanged when converting the official set to the off-brand one, even the two missing, sealed original bags might not help.
